# Collectors groupingBy insertion, ascending and descending order - java8

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, collectors

Sample Data

```
List<Test> tests = new ArrayList();

Test test3 = new Test();
test3.setName("FELLOW");
test3.setDescription("DESC FELLOW 1");
tests.add(test3);

Test test4 = new Test();
test4.setName("FELLOW");
test4.setDescription("DESC FELLOW 2");
tests.add(test4);

Test test = new Test();
test.setName("HELLO");
test.setDescription("DESC Hello 1");
tests.add(test);

Test test1 = new Test();
test1.setName("HELLO");
test1.setDescription("DESC Hello 2");
tests.add(test1);

Test test2 = new Test();
test2.setName("HELLO");
test2.setDescription("DESC Hello 3");
tests.add(test2);

Test test5 = new Test();
test5.setName("ABC");
test5.setDescription("DESC FELLOW 3");
tests.add(test5);

Test test6 = new Test();
test6.setName("ABC");
test6.setDescription("DESC ABC 1");
tests.add(test6);
```

To get data in insertion order, I used **LinkedHashMap**

```
Map<String, List<Test>> insertionOrder = tests.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getName, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

result:

```
FELLOW,
HELLO
ABC
```

To get data in ascending order, I used **TreeMap**

```
Map<String, List<Test>> ascendingOrder = tests.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getName, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

result:

```
ABC,
FELLOW
HELLO
```

How to get Map in descending order ? for example ?

```
HELLO,
FELLOW
ABC
```

Comment: `TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)`

Answer (score 3):

Pass a `Comparator` to the `TreeMap` constructor. For example:

```java
Map<String, List<Test>> descendingOrder = tests.stream().collect(
     Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getName,
                          () -> new TreeMap(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
                          Collectors.toList()));
```

Or:

```java
Map<String, List<Test>> descendingOrder = tests.stream().collect(
     Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getName,
                          () -> new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder()),
                          Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Thank Gave idea `Map<String, List<Test>> descendingOrder1 = tests.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getName, () -> new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder()), Collectors.toList()));` working !

Comment: Why not just `Comparator.reverseOrder()` such as `Map<String, List<Test>> ascendingOrder =
                tests.stream()
                     .collect(groupingBy(Test::getName,
                                         () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
                                         Collectors.toList()));`?

Comment: @davidxxx sometimes the first solution that comes to my mind is not the simplest solution. Your solution also works.

Comment: We rather stumble upon `Collections.reverseOrder(Collections.reverseOrder())` when revising old code, as `Comparator.naturalOrder()` did not exist prior to Java 8…